# Average each hour's meter readings

Tags: excel, if-statement, average, hour

I have two columns of data with five or six meter readings each hour:

```
time (HH:MM:SS) (C3:C103)        meter readings (D3:D103).
```

I would like to average each hour's readings to condense the data down to one averaged meter reading per hour.

I tried `=Averageif(C3:C103,Hour=10,D3:D103)` but clearly have something wrong.

Comment: add a column specifically for the hour, and then put it in a pivot table.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have just time values in `C3:C103` (not with dates) then you could get your results like this:

List the numbers 0 to 23 in F2 down then use this formula in G2 copied down

`=AVERAGEIFS(D$3:D$103,C$3:C$103,">="&F2/24,C$3:C$103,"<"&(F2+1)/24)`

That will give you a table with the results for each hour

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with one formula.

The following is an Array formula (need to press `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `Enter`, instead of just Enter to add it), and works for anything in the 10 o'clock hour.

```
{=AVERAGE(IF(HOUR(C3:C55)=10,D3:D55))}
```

Again, type the formula without the curly brackets then hold down `Ctrl` + `Shift` then press `Enter`

Basically the formula looks at the hour of each entry, checks to see if it is 10, then averages the adjacent numbers if the previous condition is true.

ALTERNATIVE:

You don't need a formula at all, (or any helper columns) if you just use a pivot table.

1. Select your data
2. Add your time column to the Row Labels section of the pivot table
3. add your meter readings column to the values section
4. In the Pivot table right-click on the meter readings data and select `Show Values As ... Average` in the menu.
5. In the pivot table, right-click on the time data and select the group option. In the option box select `Hours` only, and click OK.

That will give you the average for each hour without any additional formulas. It's also nice because it requires little maintenance after you have created, other than refreshing each time you get new data.

Comment: You could choose then to group by day in the pivot table as well, but since the OP stated that the data was HH:MM:SS only, I assumed it didn't have date information included.

Comment: I disagree with your statement that average of the noon hour across multiple days is useless. I use similar calculations in my line of business and it can act as a very good baseline.

Answer (score 0):

solution for my comment earlier:

This is easily done with a pivot table.  First, break down the HH:MM:SS column down into an hours column only (since you want it grouped by hours).  Then put all of the data into a pivot table, and put the 'hours' column in the row labels, and the meter readings (make sure to do an average, not a count) in the values field.  This should be what you need.